# Scala: Covariant function

Tags: scala, generics

Let say we have code snippet below

```
 trait Foo

  class Bar extends Foo

  def foobar(fn: Option[Set[_ <: Foo] => Unit]) {}

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  foobar(Option(bar)) //doesnt compile
  }

  def bar(input: Set[Bar]) {}
```

It doest compile because function one is defined as `trait Function1 [-T1, +R]  extends AnyRef` .  My Question is there anyway in Scala to write a function that takes a Type T or its subtype and do something? or as I fear its impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the type constraints for the `Set` in `foobar` out to a type parameter on the function itself:

```
trait Foo {

  class Bar extends Foo

  def foobar[A <: Foo](fn: Option[Set[A] => Unit]) {}

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      foobar(Option(bar _)) //compiles!
  }

  def bar(input: Set[Bar]) {}

}
```

The Scala compiler will infer the type `A` from the argument passed into `foobar`, while still enforcing the type constraint.  Also, you need to partially apply `bar` to pass it in an `Option` like that.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
trait Foo

class Bar extends Foo

def bar(input: Set[_ <: Foo]) {}

def foobar(fn: Option[Set[_ <: Foo] => Unit]) {}

foobar(Some(bar(_)))  // partially applied

foobar(None)
```

You can now do something like this to fully apply foobar() in the Some case

```
 val x = Set(new Bar())

 foobar(Some( x => bar(x)))
```

Note that it has to be x => bar(x) because the type is Some of a function object, not of the function's result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use existentials rather than Jesse's answer, you could have something like:

```
def foobar(fn: Option[(Set[X] => Unit) forSome { type X <: Foo }]) {}
foobar(Option(bar _))
```